# Is a question closed with the message "Your post has been associated with a similar question", detrimental to your account/reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, closed-questions

I created a question on Stack Overflow. The Internet is flooded with answers to a very similar question; and in the writing process I found an answer to what I was writing. The wording was different, and perhaps that is the reason I couldn't find it in the first place.

So I decided to post my question plus an answer linking the answer found. Minutes later I found the question closed, and a message "Your post has been associated with a similar question".

Is that something detrimental for my account and reputation?

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312170/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360211/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356115/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243899/is-it-encouraged-to-intentionally-post-duplicates-for-searchability/314125#comment797229_243899

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68553800) appears to be the question in question.

Comment: See our FAQ [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled): the section *Is there a penalty for asking a duplicate question?* addresses your question. I'd *highly* suggest reading the rest of that FAQ, though; it explains why it's a bad idea to post such things.

Comment: Duplicates can be positive, if they show research, if you ask a question that shows zero research it will be treated the same as any question that shows zero research.  Answering a question, you know is a duplicate, is most definitely NOT positive especially if the answer is a sign post that only contains a link to the existing question

Comment: Also your question really isn't a question when it comes to SO standards. It's just one sentence with some obscured hyperlinks. Try to flesh it out next time. What is it that you are trying to do, and what is the problem you are facing. Asking a one-line question like you did, that looks like it's easily found in a manual doesn't help you very much.

Comment: One more important note. Posting poor questions can lead to question ban. However, you get the chance to ask new question every six months in that case and you can eventually get out of it. Posting poor answers leads to answer ban and once you get banned and you don't have any other good answers at that point to eventually pull you out, you will not be able to post answers ever.

Comment: thanks for the comments. After reading the similar questions, and the FAQ, everything is clear.