# Opinion-based questions and answers should be allowed

Tags: feature-request, questions, closed-questions, policy

The policy/rule/guideline of the Stack Exchange network of restricting opinion-based questions and answers may have good motivations, but I think it restricts too much the free flow of information and it has in my opinion restricted the reach and growth of the Stack Exchange family of websites.

People who come here to ask a question who get shut down because it may generate an opinion-based answer, goes to another website and many never come back again. This has led to the the bigger success of Quora (which has visitor traffic, if I’m not mistaken, [two or three times](https://www.seoreviewtools.com/website-traffic-checker/) as much as Stack Exchange) as a question and answer website, because people can almost ask anything they want.

In order to attract more users, censor less and help more, I think it would be a good idea if Stack Exchange and its network of sites drop the policy/rule of banning opinion-based questions and answers; questions that may be opinion-based can have a special label.

I guess administrators of this website can check if visitor traffic to the site has grown, stalled or dropped through the years. One possible scenario is that Quora becomes to questions and answers as Google became to search queries, dominating 90% of the market. Flexibility is the key to success.

Comment: Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333476/common-reasons-why-your-meta-post-may-be-negatively-received/333477#333477)

Comment: Quora is an awful comparison, all you get on there is idiots shouting or posting memes full of grammar and spelling errors, there is less and less good content on there everyday. SE's rules keep standards up and that is what matters in the long run. Look at Yahoo answers, totally dead and Quora is soon to follow.

Comment: @MarkKirby I doubt Quora will die out.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica OK perhaps that is a bit hyperbole but I am not alone in saying that the quality has fallen so low there it is useless now. Don't get me wrong, I hope it gets back on its feet but since they opened it up to any rubbish, stopped a lot of moderation and monetized the processes it has been going downhill.

Comment: @MarkKirby Mining companies mine gold for a profit even though to get one single ounce of gold they need to sift and process thousands of pounds of rock. The censorship movement wants to stop looking for precious gems and minerals because it may take a lot of sifting through useless material.

Comment: @freethinker36 Sorry what censorship movement are you talking about?

Comment: The online censorship movement. It's pervassive everywhere online nowadays. I miss the old glory days of the internet where one could say pretty much anything.

Comment: SE not allowing subjective questions isn't censorship, the sites have a topic and a format that open ended or subjective questions simply don't fit in. No one is been censored.

Comment: I would rather have all my nails removed, one centimeter at a time, than have Stack Exchange turn into the trash that is Quora.  A community that allows users to purchase answers to their questions.  They also force you to register an account in order to see accounts, an action entirely designed, so they can sell your information to the highest bidder.  **Did I mention Quora is trash?**

Comment: Quora actually has interesting content, but it is mostly for entertainment and has little actual utility. It is not a real Q&A site (effectively only a ***single*** sentence is allowed for a question (question details was removed)), but has moved closer to a previous characterisation as "provoked blogging". Moderation, tagging of questions, and *rejection* of edit suggestions *by default* (it takes an enormous amount of effort to correct even obvious spelling mistakes) is all automatic by bots of unspecified IQ, not real humans (or in other words, a disgrace).

Comment: Can you add some examples of such questions? You could also use the tags *[big-list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/big-list)* and *[big-picture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/big-picture)* on Stack Exchange site [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour) as examples of how it could work well.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I have seen the issue of questions shut down due to being opinion-based which is why I bring the suggestion forth, but I don't have examples at hand right now. You have 6k rep, you probably have seen more than a few examples.

Comment: @freethinker36 'Mining companies mine gold for a profit' indeed, and they pay their workers to actually do the mining.  If you are suggesting that high-rep SE contributors should be paid for handling opinion-based questions, I'm all for it.

Comment: @MartinJames Well, then maybe Stack Exchange should put a donate button next to each answer. I would gladly pay for some answers.

Answer (score 9):

You could go to existing forums the Internet over if you want to facilitate opinionated and open discussion.

The Stack Exchange network is explicitly oriented around **questions and answers**.

I won't disagree that [this comes with its own set of problems](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4372/102), and some domains or some questions are simply not going to fit this mold.  But that doesn't mean that it makes sense to change if we're able to suit and fit the niche we're good at well.

Comment: Answer well asked questions please.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica:  I do.  Disagreeing with a question's premise is not to equate it to it being a poorly-asked question.

Comment: @Makato duplicates are not well asked questions.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica:  Dupes aren't *bad*, either.  They're just answered somewhere else. I did look at that other dupe and I feel like there's a lot more noise in the premise of those answers that would serve to confuse and/or lose someone as opposed to cutting the chase and saying it straight.  I'd rather close *that* question as a duplicate of *this* at this rate.

Comment: Why make the remark that I can go to existing forums elsewhere? I am making a suggestion for this site evidently. Do you think I don't know I can go to another website or is that a way to show me the door because I made a suggestion?

Comment: Don't take such sharp umbrage to it, @freethinker36.  I'm simply explaining the fences we have around here.  If you want questions and answers, look no further.  If you want the opportunity to facilitate discussion or opinion, you'll have to look elsewhere.  If you *only* want the latter, then you should start looking elsewhere.  If you're cool with our constraints, though, you'll find that Stack Exchange is a pretty good network that can provide a lot of value as you look for answers to your questions.

Comment: @Makoto It is hillarious that you fail to realize I posted this as a suggestion to modify that fence you are talking about and you keep on the loop telling me to go elsewhere like if I couldn't realize I can go elsewhere. Evidently my suggestion didn't get traction among other users, so I see it doesn't have support. Oh well. Good day.

Comment: @freethinker36: [Good fences make good neighbors.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Good+fences+make+good+neighbors) You're gonna need to work *extra* hard to convince us that it's worth messing with the fence in the first place.